# pushing a shopping cart after a trip to the supermarket

Tags: comprehension

Example with a context ([Russia's pro-Putin media darling loves his new life in Brooklyn — minus the hipsters](http://mashable.com/2015/05/01/russia-lifenews-founder-loves-nyc/)):

> Babo, a mobile app that connects citizen reporters with media organizations, is how LifeNews obtained the first images of NSA intelligence whistleblower Edward Snowden as he began his new life in Russia, **pushing a shopping cart after a trip to the supermarket**.

What's that actually supposed to mean? I totally don't get it. Snowden, shopping carts? What's that all about?

Comment: Snowden is a name. A shopping cart is the thing you push groceries around in. A supermarket is a place to buy groceries. Person went to supermarket to buy groceries, and someone took a picture of him pushing the cart.

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? Is it not clear that Snowden is a person? Do you know what the words 'shopping cart' and 'supermarket' mean? If not, did you try a dictionary? The way your question is now, we have to **guess** at which parts you understand and what you do not. Why make us guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break the sentence down to pieces, to examine it molecule by molecule:

> Babo, *a mobile app that connects citizen reporters with media organizations*,

The italicized phrase is called [an appositive](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/appositive_apposition.htm). Appositives give further info about the noun in the main sentence. It's OK to remove them from the sentence structure to understand the main sentence better. Here, I can write an independent sentence using the words above with replacing the commas with a *be* verb and a full stop, respectively:

> > Babo **is** *a mobile app that connects citizen reporters with media organizations* **.**

Hope it's clear there. I recommend doing like me the next time a sentence bothers you. :)

> ...is how LifeNews obtained the first images of NSA intelligence whistleblower Edward Snowden as he began his new life in Russia, pushing a shopping cart after a trip to the supermarket.

This is the main body of the sentence. You can boil the sentence down to this [imaginary] structure to understand it better: *{Babo, an app, is [how LifeNews obtained the images of Snowden (as he began a new life) ] }*

These might be the source of confusion here:

> - Whistleblower: One who reveals wrongdoing within an organization to the public or to those in positions of authority. [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whistleblower)

- The main concept of the sentence:
  It was just a few days since Snowden has arrived. He went to a shop to buy some groceries. He carried the goods he wanted to buy in a shopping cart. (See the image below) An enthusiast saw him, and took some images. Too excited to sit still, the enthusiast sent the photos to LifeNews via an app named Babo. These were the first images from Snowden in Russia.

Most possibly due to emphasis, the author intended to bring the app as the subject of the sentence. The seemingly contradictory fact about how effective an app can be, would engage the reader in reading the rest of the article with much more delight.

---

A shopping cart:
  [image]

Comment: Cautionary note: to native speakers, *degrade* has heavy negative overtones. You might prefer to say "*Let's break the question down"*, or something similar.

Comment: Ahh @Dan that was supposed to be the humor of a Chem nerd. :) Well, edited now. Thanks for pointing out.